# Harvard Mark 1 decimal digits

Tags: decimal

The Harvard Mark 1 computer has 72 words of 23 decimal digits each, does this mean that each word contains 23 binary digits that represent 1 decimal digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, at least the registers of that computer really stored decimal digits. It was electromechanical, the storage may have involved wheels.

This has some pictures in it:
http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/harvard/MarkI_operMan_1946.pdf